# jQuery fetching a file each time toggle() is called error

Tags: jquery, post, pageload

I have this jQuery script:

```
$(".show-div").data('loaded',false).click(function() {
    $.post("script.php", {id_1: var_id_1, id_2: var_id_2}, function(data){
        $(this).data('loaded',true);
        $("#display").html(data);
    });

    $("#display").toggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

That loads a page (script.php) and displays its content inside the `#display` div from the current page. Now, what I'm trying to do is load `script.php` only the first time the `.show-div` is clicked, but instead it gets loaded each time. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'd probably want to remove the click handler after the first successful call, other it will stay bound the entire time.

Comment: @j08691. But he still want to `toggle` `#display`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".show-div").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('loaded'))  // <====
    {
        $.post("script.php", {id_1: var_id_1, id_2: var_id_2}, function(data){
            $("#display").html(data);
            $(this).data('loaded',true);
        });
    }

    $("#display").toggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Another way to go:

```
$(".show-div").one('click', function() {
    $.post("script.php", { id_1: var_id_1, id_2: var_id_2}, function(data) {
            $("#display").html(data);});
    return false;
}).click(function() {
    $("#display").toggle('fast');
    return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if data('loaded') is true, don't make ajax call if it is

```
$(".show-div").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    /* check if loaded*/
    if (!$this.data('loaded')) {// only call ajax first time
        $.post("script.php", {id_1: var_id_1,id_2: var_id_2}, function(data) {
            $this.data('loaded', true);
            $("#display").html(data);
        });

    }
    $("#display").toggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$(".show-div").data('loaded', false).click` No need to init data-loaded, as it will be undefined by default..